# Spring AOP MDC Logging not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot, aop, mdc

In my code, I have 2 methods `processInbound()` and `processOutbound()`. I am trying to use AOP to load MDC data so that in the logs I can identify the journey.

My code is working as I can see the desired journey details in the log.

Following is my method

```java
public void processInboundData() {
  //Do get journey details in the following info
  log.info("In the method processInboundData");

  //Method i call to process the data
  //Do get journey details in all info's defined in  fetchAndSaveData method
  ddlDataService.fetchAndSaveData();

  //Don't get journey=Inbound in the following info
  log.info("After done");
}
```

This is the Aspect

```java
@Around("execution(*package.processInboundData(..))")
public Object processInboundData(final ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
  MDC.put(Journey , "Inbound");
  try {
     // invoke the method.
     return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
  } finally { 
     MDC.clear();
  }
}
```

The problem that I can see is that in the logs I do get the log lines with the correct journey name in the following lines:

> processInboundData - [journey=Inbound] - [] In the method
> processInboundData

I also get "[journey=Inbound]" in all the info lines that are there in the called method "fetchAndSaveData"

But I don't get "[journey=Inbound]" in the line just after the method call returns, so the logline shows up as with the missing "[journey=Inbound]".

> processInboundData -  - [] After done

Not sure why is this happening

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your logline is `processInboundData - - [] After done` but in your code inside `processInboundData()` method you are logging `After method call`. Is this a typo or is `After done` logged somewhere else?

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo, i have updated it.

Comment: Thanks R.G , i have checked and the fetchAndSaveData method has MDC.clear which clears the context. . Instead i have used  MDC.remove to clear the specific key. Thanks to all who contributed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to R.G, the called method at the end was doing MDC.clear(). I had to use  MDC.remove method to remove the specific key used in the method fetchAndSaveData()

Comment: So that means you have another `@Around` for `fetchAndSaveData()`?